# How can I host a simple .exe file as a "SaaS" on Azure?

Tags: azure, cloud, virtual-machine, azure-active-directory

I have a simple calculator.exe that I want to host on Azure, that I want people to access and utilize its services. Is creating a Virtual Machine and later hosting my .exe on it(and sharing this VM instance to multiple users) the only way to host it on Azure or is there any other process by which I can only add my .exe and let multiple users access it?

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to understand these services better so any help/suggestions/link would be appreciated!

Comment: Azure used to have Remote Apps, but those have been discontinued. Have a look over here to find their recommended alternatives: [Options for migrating out of Azure RemoteApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/remoteapp/remoteapp-migrationoptions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This more fits the use case of RemoteApp rather than Azure itself. Azure does not have the functionality to simply upload an exe and have users consume it in a SaaS-type way.

The best way to achieve this is one of 2 ways:

- Create a VM, install the app and then have users connect to the VM over RDP to consume the application
- Create a VM, configure for RDS and RemoteApp, publish the remote app and users can consume the app without having to RDP to the VM first

There are some good guides out there for this (https://msfreaks.wordpress.com/2013/12/09/windows-2012-r2-remote-desktop-services-part-1/)

Comment: @rahul-ramesh Did the answer help? Let me know if you have more questions

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the reply and sorry for the dealy. I guess the first point you mentioned is the only way to go about it as RemoteApp service has been discontinued. I was hoping to build an app with a similar use case of Office365, that users could directly access rather than accessing it through the vm.

Answer (score 0):

Can you transform your app to a webservice? That way you would have a lot less hassle about VM's and other services to provide this. In my opinion, when you are designing a new application, you should aim to stay away from VM's. I do not see another solution to run your .exe (as you intend) in Azure at this time.

Comment: Like you pointed out, I guess there is no other way apart from hosting my application in a vm as of now. And unfortunately no, I wont be able to transform the app to a webservice. thanks for the reply.